# How to resolve "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'" when trying to connect to database?

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using MySQLdb library. I'm getting an error message that the function has no cursor attribute.

I tried running the connection code line by line without wrapping it in a function in the interpreter and it works without error.

```py
import MySQLdb
import databaseconfig as dcfg
# databaseconfig.py contains the database credentials
# It is a config file and has no code


def mysqlconnect():
    # Trying to connect
    db_connection = None
    try:
        db_connection = MySQLdb.connect
        (
            dcfg.mysql["host"],
            dcfg.mysql["user"],
            dcfg.mysql["password"],
            dcfg.mysql["db"],
            dcfg.mysql["port"]
        )
    # If connection is not successful
    except:
        print("Can't connect to database")
        return 0
    # If Connection Is Successful
    print("Connected")

    # Making Cursor Object For Query Execution
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

# Function Call For Connecting To Our Database
mysqlconnect()
```

Expected output is that a cursor is generated. 
Actual output is:

```
Connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 43, in <module>
    mysqlconnect()
  File "models.py", line 26, in mysqlconnect
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: `db_connection = MySQLdb.connect` is a complete statement, that assigns a *function itself* where the result of calling that function is intended.  You need to move the open parenthesis of the parameter list onto the same line, so that Python will extend the statement until the matching close parentheses.  (As it is, your parameter list gets parsed as a tuple construction which is then discarded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of your syntax. your `mysqlconnect` function should be like this:

```
def mysqlconnect():
    # Trying to connect
    db_connection = None
    try:
        db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(
            dcfg.mysql["host"],
            dcfg.mysql["user"],
            dcfg.mysql["password"],
            dcfg.mysql["db"],
            dcfg.mysql["port"]
        )
    # If connection is not successful
    except:
        print("Can't connect to database")
        return 0
    # If Connection Is Successful
    print("Connected")

    # Making Cursor Object For Query Execution
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
```